# VB6 ActiveX exe loses focus when launched from a third party app

Tags: vb6, activex, focus

I have a VB6 ActiveX exe that is launched from a third-party CRM App. On launch, the main form opens but it starts to flash and then loses focus. If you move the form, you'll see a server busy screen with the **Switch To**, **Retry** button.

I've tried using SetFocus and the SetFocusAPI in the OnActivate event of the form, but that doesn't work. Are there any suggestions on how I can have this form have focus when launched from the other app?

**Additional Info:**

The OnLoad event calls the SetWindowPos API in order to center the app over the calling app and sets HWND_TOPMOST.

**Additional Info:**

- The Active Window is the correct window(but it's clearly not in focus)
- The foreground window is the calling application. SetForegroundWindow switches the foreground window, but immediately returns back to the calling app. It's not until I click on the form that the form is in the foreground. I'm attempting all of this within a loop in the module that calls the form (and not in the calling app).

Comment: SOLUTION: Use Mouse_event to simulate a mouse click on the blinking form.

Answer (score 1):

The CRM application has to call [`AllowSetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632668(VS.85).aspx) to "authorize" the ActiveX `ProcessID` to "steal" the focus from the current process.

Comment: Unfortunately, the calling app doesn't allow API Calls.

Comment: Without AllowSet... there is no legitimate way to change focus to a window which is owned by another process in XP and above. AllowSet... informs the OS 'He is with me. Treat his windows as mine, regarding focus'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the tab order on the form? Your user control should have a tab order of 0 so it gets the focus.

Also, where does the focus go after it is launched?

Comment: I'm not sure, how setting the forms tab order will affect the focus of the form itself, however the tab order 0 is set to the frame, 1 to a label next to a textbox and 2 to the text box within that frame.

I added additional info above.